# where to find the file `slf4j-api.jar'

Tags: python, jar, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use `NLTK` combined with `Stanford Segmenter` for Chinese word segmentation, but get stuck at the very beginning. I don't know where to find the file `slf4j-api.jar`. 
I am not familiar with `JAVA`. It will be greate if you could explain me the function of this file.

Answer (score 0):

SLF4J is a library that ease building a logging system at deployment time. You can download the library directly from their site: https://www.slf4j.org/download.html.

If you are using Manven you can use the following dependency:

> ```
> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
> <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
> <version>1.7.25</version>
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have downloaded the link and the file `slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar` does exist. I am wondering if this file is just an interface or it could be customized for particular software? What really concerns me is if I can use this downloaded file without any modification and without any compatibility problems.

Comment: As you can see (https://www.slf4j.org/license.html) the license type is MIT. This means that you can use it without any problems as long as you  include a copy of the MIT License terms and the copyright notice.